# mysql - reading the last data of each day

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql talbel like below and I want to read the last data of each day in "one" query

[mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZBG5.jpg)

could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2013-01-02 09:43:00' AS trade_time, 515.61 AS price UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-03 09:39:00', 525.90 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-03 11:38:00', 539.44 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-03 13:22:00', 509.16 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-04 09:47:00', 507.40 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-04 14:33:00', 517.45 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-07 09:33:00', 550.42 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-07 13:13:00', 524.85 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-01-07 14:51:00', 536.44
)

SELECT t1.trade_time, t1.price
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(trade_time) AS trade_date, MAX(trade_time) AS max_trade_time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE(trade_time)
) t2
    ON t2.trade_date = DATE(t1.trade_time) AND
       t2.max_trade_time = t1.trade_time
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f56a245f4ba66668371a2af5805cde90